# Why is Elastic IP *needed* for CNAME/ A/ AAAA records (public ip's don't work)

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, terraform

I am using terraform to provision an EC2 instance and then create DNS records pointing to it. On AWS, Static ip addresses are recommended over public ip addresses so that changing ip addresses when restarting does not cause issues. But with terraform, DNS records will be updated with either the new public IP/ public DNS. **So, in theory, I do not need elastic IP addresses.**

Without **eip**, I am still able to SSH using the public IP address, and public DNS/ hostname provided by AWS. But, when pointing a DNS record (A, or CNAME) to the public IP address & public DNS, SSH times out. This happens even when the DNS records propagate (I checked with dig domain.com *and* a global DNS propagation checker). Looks like something is blocking access from non IP-address/ non aws public DNS hosts.

**Has anyone had this issue with pointing DNS records directly to public IPs/ public DNSs?**

Comment: You can use public IP for DNS. The public IP keeps changing whenever you stop/start the instance. When it's EIP then it will not change, so it's just best practice to use EIP for DNS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh wow. It turns out it WAS the DNS record in the end... After typing up the question, I retried, and it worked. For some reason initially, `dig` returned the updated record, but `ssh` was using the old record? How is this possible!

**Why does SSH use the old record? I can clearly get the correct record using `dig`**.

The answer is DNS caching! Even though dig would give me the latest DNS records from Cloudflare's DNS servers, my computer was using old ones. So I had to flush the DNS. On mac, I used `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`. Then this brought a DNS Spoofing detected message, so I had to update the known_hosts folder, using `ssh-keygen -R domain.com`

> The dig command does not use the host name and address resolution or the DNS query routing mechanisms used by other processes processes running on macOS.

from [Dig macOS man page](https://ss64.com/osx/dig.html)

Comment: I wanted to add, the DNS records updated extremely quickly, probably because I use Cloudflare. When using Route53 and other DNS hosting providers, I found that the TTL was set quite high.

Nevertheless, static IPs are useful, because this problem could happen to users: their DNS cache would prevent them from accessing the new website